# darkmode with vuex and save in localstorage

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a chrome bug telling me Write operation failed: computed property "isDark" is readonly.

my mutation create a DarkMode key in the locastorage and I also create a store that checks if DarkMode exists in the localestorage

it works but if I refresh the page the mutation is inverted for example if in the localestorage darkMode is true if I click on the toggle the mutation is also a true then what should return false

My Page

````
  <div id="home">
    <div class="toggleTheme">
      <ToggleBtnTheme
        labelOn="Dark"
        labelOff="Light"
        v-model:value="isDark"
        @input="mode"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <h1 :class="isDark ? 'dark' : 'light'">Lidian Manoha</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import ToggleBtnTheme from '@/components/atoms/ToggleBtn/index';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    ToggleBtnTheme
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapMutations('themeDarkMode', ['toggleDarkMode']),
    mode() {
      this.toggleDarkMode();
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('themeDarkMode', ['isDark'])
  },
  watch: {}
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" src="./style.scss" scoped></style>```

My Stores

    ```   return {
          darkMode: true,
          isDark: false
        };
      },
      getters: DarkModeGetters,
      mutations: DarkModeMutations,
      action: DarkModeAction
    };
    
    ```

My getters.js

    ```
    export default {
      isDark: state => state.isDark
    };
    ```

My mutations.js

    ```
    export default {
      toggleDarkMode: state => {
        state.isDark = !state.isDark;
        console.log('mutation', state.isDark);
        localStorage.setItem('DarkMode', JSON.stringify(state.isDark));
      }
    };```

And my ToggleBtn

    ```<template>
      <div id="toggleBtn">
        <div class="toggleBtnContainer">
          <label class="label" v-if="label">{{ label }}</label>
          <div class="containerToggle">
            <input
              v-bind="$attrs"
              :id="`toggle${uuid}`"
              :disabled="disabled"
              type="checkbox"
              :checked="value || checked"
              @change="$emit('update:value', $event.target.checked)"
            />
            <label
              :for="`toggle${uuid}`"
              v-html="value ? labelOn : labelOff"
              @click="$emit('click', $event)"
            ></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { uuid } from 'vue-uuid';
    
    export default {
      name: 'toggleBtn',
      inheritAttrs: false,
      props: {
        value: { type: [Boolean, String, Number, Function], default: false },
        checked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        labelOn: { type: String, default: 'off' },
        labelOff: { type: String, default: 'on' },
        label: { type: String, default: null },
        disabled: { type: Boolean, default: false }
      },
      data() {
        return {
          uuid: uuid.v4()
        };
      }
    };
    </script>
    
    <style lang="scss" src="./style.scss" scoped></style>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats probably because you missed a point. When you refresh the page...ie the app reloads... if you find that there is a data('Darkmode') available in the local storage then you need to set it through the mutation in the first place. By doing so what happens is when you refresh the page...if darkmode is already set to true then your vuex state('isDark') will also be set to true. Therefore when you click on that it will toggle as expected.

Its better to have two mutations to avoid confusions

```
My mutations.js

   
    export default {
      toggleDarkMode: state => {
        state.isDark = !state.isDark;
        console.log('mutation', state.isDark);
        localStorage.setItem('DarkMode', JSON.stringify(state.isDark));
      },
      initializeDarkMode: (state, payload) => {
        state.isDark = payload; // payload is actually the value that was stored in the local storage
      }
    };
```

When the app loads, just call the second mutation to initialize the state with the local storage value.

```
  this.initializeDarkMode(DarkMode);  // DarkMode contains the value fetched from local storage
```

Below I have modified the code to call the second mutation

```
  <div id="home">
    <div class="toggleTheme">
      <ToggleBtnTheme
        labelOn="Dark"
        labelOff="Light"
        v-model:value="isDarkMode" // ****************Changes added ***************** 
        @input="mode"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <h1 :class="isDark ? 'dark' : 'light'">Lidian Manoha</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import ToggleBtnTheme from '@/components/atoms/ToggleBtn/index';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    ToggleBtnTheme
  },
  data() {
    return {
     isDarkMode: this.isDark,
     },
   
  watch: {
     isDark(newVal) {
       this.isDarkMode = newVal;
     }
  },
// ****************Changes added below ***************** 
  mounted() { 
   const isDark = localStorage.getItem('DarkMode');
   if(isDark && isDark === 'true') {
       this.initializeDarkMode(true); 
       this.isDarkMode = true;
    } else {
      this.initializeDarkMode(false);
      this.isDarkMode = false;
  }
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations('themeDarkMode', ['toggleDarkMode', 'initializeDarkMode']),
    mode() {
      this.toggleDarkMode();
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('themeDarkMode', ['isDark'])
  },
  watch: {}
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" src="./style.scss" scoped></style>
```

Comment: thank you very much on the other hand I have to put this.initializeDarkMode (DarkMode); // DarkMode contains the value fetched from local storage

Comment: are you asking me if you need to include the second mutation?

Comment: I want to know where I should call this.initializeDarkMode (DarkMode); in my code?

sorry I'm still a beginner with vue and vuex

Comment: Dont feel sorry...check my updated answer

Comment: thank you but he tells me that DarkMode is not defined in this.initializeDarkMode(DarkMode);

Comment: I found it was necessary to put this.initializeDarkMode ('DarkMode')

on the other hand i still have an error in the console Write operation failed: computed property "isDark" is readonly.
how can I resolve this thank you

Comment: for that readonly error..I will update my answer please give me a moment

Comment: the reason is that you are trying to use the vuex state(isDark) in your v-model

Comment: check the edited answer and see if that works

Comment: Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. You can read about accepting here: stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: No worries how we vote for you?

otherwise I rejoiced too quickly isDarkMode code: this.isDark? 'Dark': 'Light' return me always Dark

Comment: I have edited the mounted() function...pls check the updated answer

Comment: no it doesn't work on the other hand I see in the console that it does 2x the toggle when I click

Comment: Please check the watch block I have added above the mounted()

Comment: no it doesn't work the toggle no longer works visually   I have this in the console                                     mutation false
backend.js:2747 {uid: 14, vnode: {…}, type: {…}, parent: {…}, appContext: {…}, …}
backend.js:2747 {uid: 14, vnode: {…}, type: {…}, parent: {…}, appContext: {…}, …}
backend.js:2747 {uid: 14, vnode: {…}, type: {…}, parent: {…}, appContext: {…}, …}

Comment: Can you check now?

Comment: the toggle visual works again but when I refresh it stays on Dark

Comment: I think it's good I deleted this.isDarkMode = 'Dark'; and this.isDarkMode = 'Light'; mounted and it seems ok

Comment: no dont do that...I have updated the mounted() part just check it

Comment: Fine...then just crosscheck all actions nd hit me an upvote dude thanks...:)

Comment: sorry i have to do what to vote for you? if yes or should I do this

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you

Comment: To upvote...you just need to click the upArrow above the greentick

Comment: Iam suggesting you to do that becoz I too can upvote your question so that your reputation will increase

Comment: here it is done normally and again thank you for your time and your help