# how to refresh the value of computed when it changes

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to change the value of: class = "`theme - $ {nightMode}`" when I click toggle but it only works if I refresh the page and I can't figure out how to set up a watcher so that 'he looks at the value modify

````
  ```  <template>
  <div id="app" :class="`theme-${nightMode}`">
    <router-view />
    <Header />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/components/molecules/Header/index.vue';
import Footer from '@/components/molecules/Footer/index.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: { Header, Footer },
  data() {
    return {
      themeMode: ''
    };
  },

  computed: {
    nightMode() {
      const mode = localStorage.getItem('DarkMode');
      if (mode === 'true') {
        console.log('dark');
        return 'dark';
      } else {
        console.log('light');
        return 'light';
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    themeMode(newVal) {
      this.nightMode = newVal;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" src="./assets/scss/style.scss"></style>```
````

Comment: the localstorage works the value is good to change it is only the style of the class that is not changed

Comment: where have you defined the toggle function?

Comment: @Amaarrockz hello the toggle is in my header you helped me on this one yesterday `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65807129/darkmode-with-vuex-and-save-in-localstorage/65807258#65807258`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the changes

````
       <template>
         <div id="app" :class="`theme-${themeMode}`">
           <router-view />
           <Header />
           <Footer />
         </div>
       </template>
       
       <script>
       import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'; // change Added
       import Header from '@/components/molecules/Header/index.vue';
       import Footer from '@/components/molecules/Footer/index.vue';
       
       export default {
         name: 'App',
       
         components: { Header, Footer },
         data() {
           return {
             themeMode: 'light' // change Added
           };
         },
         computed: {
           ...mapGetters(['isDark']) // change Added
         },
         watch: { // change Added
           isDark(newVal) {
            this.themeMode = newVal ? 'dark' : 'light';
          }
         },
         mounted() {
           const mode = localStorage.getItem('DarkMode');
           if (mode === 'true') {
               console.log('dark');
               return 'dark';
             } else {
               console.log('light');
               return 'light';
           }
         }
       };
       </script>
       
       <style lang="scss" src="./assets/scss/style.scss"></style>
       ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can't updating computed value by doing things like `this.nightMode = newVal;`.
Even if this is possible (I guess no) this would be missusing the vue framwork.

I think that it would be better to init themeMode inside the mounted (or created) hook see below:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :class="appClass">
    <router-view />
    <Header />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/components/molecules/Header/index.vue';
import Footer from '@/components/molecules/Footer/index.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: { Header, Footer },
  data() {
    return {
      themeMode: '',
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const mode = localStorage.getItem('DarkMode');
    this.themeMode = mode === 'true' ? 'dark' : 'light';
  },
  computed: {
    appClass() {
      return `theme-${this.themeMode}`;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

Actually your toogle define in Home component is not modifying your local data `themeMode`, instead, it modify the `isDark` state of your vuex store.
=> You should directly use the `isDark` state to set you class:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :class="appClass">
    <router-view />
    <Header />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/components/molecules/Header/index.vue';
import Footer from '@/components/molecules/Footer/index.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: { Header, Footer },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.commit('initializeDarkMode', localStorage.getItem('DarkMode'));
  },
  computed: {
    appClass() {
      return `theme-${this.$store.state.isDark === 'true' ? 'dark' : 'light'}`;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I have exactly the same result as with my code the class does not update

Comment: I use a toggle which is in my header page you have the code here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65807129/darkmode-with-vuex-and-save-in-localstorage/65807258#65807258`

Comment: ok I understand your issue.
I''l update my answer

Comment: it does not work but the solution of Amaarrockz worked thank you